# How late in the spring can I plant a citrus tree in Phoenix, Arizona?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, citrus, planting-times

Due to circumstances beyond my control I will only have the option of planting citrus trees at the beginning of June this year. The temperatures in Phoenix, Arizona will average highs above 100°F (38°C) throughout June. Is this too hot for new citrus trees to survive, even with daily water?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will have a good chance if you do this:

- Put a [heavy row cover](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=heavy%20row%20cover&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIIBEBYwAA&url=http://growerssolution.com/page/GS/PROD/AG125&ei=Gb6QT_O0CfGN6QG815m2BA&usg=AFQjCNEZotagGLzLDxeW3kQ5kWnoiuBWBg) on a hoop frame for shade. Keep it up off the ground, so that the bottom of the cover begins halfway up the plants for ventilation. Also, for the same reason, keep the ends open.
- Put a mister next to each tree, and keep them misted with a light mister several times a day.
- Keep them watered.

Comment: Hi J. Musser! The link in here leads to a product no longer available. I was going to switch it to something else but didn't know what the right thing was!